# Unsure how to troubleshoot NRPE issue

Tags: nagios, nrpe

If have distributed the puppet check for Nagios available from https://github.com/liquidat/nagios-icinga-checks/blob/master/check_puppetagent

My issue is that I get different results if I execute locally vs via NRPE:

```
[root@nagios-client /]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent
OK: Puppet was last run 17 minutes and 9 seconds ago
```

vs

```
[root@nagios ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.50.121 -c check_puppetagent
WARN: Puppet has never run, no /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml found.
```

Editing the file `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent` and changing the line to:
`summary = '/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summaries.yaml'` on the client yields the expected result:

```
[root@nagios ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.50.121 -c check_puppetagent
WARN: Puppet has never run, no /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summaries.yaml found.
```

So I know the correct file is being executed.

Executing it manually from remote works:

```
[root@nagios ~]# ssh 192.168.50.121 "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent"
root@192.168.50.121's password:
OK: Puppet was last run 13 seconds ago
```

Antone have any ideas/suggestions what else I can do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last_run_summaries.yaml` appears to only be readable by root:
https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7106

When you run `check_puppetagent` from the command line, you're showing that you're running as **root**.  But NRPE would likely be running `check_puppetagent` as the **nagios** user.

Try modifying your nrpe command configuration to call `sudo` before `check_puppetagent` and modify your `/etc/sudoers` file to give the **nagios** user permissions to run `check_puppetagent` as **root**.

**EDIT:** Also be sure to comment out the `Defaults requiretty` in your `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
#Defaults requiretty
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent
```

Comment: I think we are getting closer!    
From the client:    `-bash-4.2$ sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent    OK: Puppet was last run 45 seconds ago`    From nagios:    `-bash-4.2$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.50.121 -c check_puppetagent
NRPE: Unable to read output`    

The command file:    
`-bash-4.2$ cat /etc/nrpe.d/check_puppetagent.cfg
command[check_puppetagent]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent`

Comment: Seems to work for the nagios user:  `[root@nagios ~]# ssh 192.168.50.121 "su - nagios -s /bin/bash -c 'sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent'"
root@192.168.50.121's password:
OK: Puppet was last run 9 minutes and 57 seconds ago
`

Comment: Try commenting out the `Defaults requiretty` line in your sudoers file, as nrpe will be running without a terminal.

Comment: I had that commented already, more correct, puppet builds the file and excludes it by default.

Comment: Try adding the path to python before `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent` and update sudoers accordingly.  Perhaps it's having trouble finding the interpreter in the shebang.

Comment: Do any other nagios plugins work via NRPE on your system?

Comment: Yup, this is the only one that does not

Comment: Try enabling logging of NRPE in your client system:  http://www.charlesjudith.com/2014/03/11/create-a-log-file-for-nrpe/  Then check syslog after executing `check_puppetagent` via NRPE to see if there are any error messages present.

Comment: Pfft, great:
`Nov 25 17:57:50 nagios-client nrpe[30866]: Host is asking for command 'check_puppetagent' to be run...
Nov 25 17:57:50 nagios-client nrpe[30866]: Running command: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_puppetagent
Nov 25 17:57:50 nagios-client nrpe[30866]: Command completed with return code 1 and output:
Nov 25 17:57:50 nagios-client nrpe[30866]: Return Code: 1, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output`
and that is with debug mode = 1

Comment: Would you buy chance have selinux enabled?

Comment: Nope, although that would have made things  alot easier!

Comment: I'm officially out of ideas.  Last ditch effort is to check whoami and env as in step 3 here:  http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/05/debugging-nagios-remote-nrpe-commands.html  But I doubt it will find anything useful.

Comment: Thanks Joe - appreciate the help, I'll post back if I manage to get this fixed

Comment: One last thing: in the comments of the last link I posted, a user redirected stderr to stdout to get some additional output.  Give that a try and see if anything more descriptive shows up in the syslog.

Comment: Your link did it!
`[root@nagios ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.50.121 -c check_ui_test
nrpe`
Changed sudoers to reflect nrpe rather than nagios, now all good. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!